# When does message leave when Transport.sendMessage() gets called

Tags: jakarta-mail

When I am sending bulk emails using the following code, does the message leave when `t.sendMessage()` get called?

```
Transport t = session.getTransport();
t.connect();
try {
  for(Message m : messages) {
    m.saveChanges();
    t.sendMessage(m, m.getAllRecipients());
  }
} finally {
  t.close();
}
```

Comment: Yes. It doesn't batch them.

Comment: The message is sent from your application to the mail server.  The mail server may queue the message before sending it to the recipient's mail server, which may queue the message before delivering it to the recipient.